# Installing MariaDB Encryption at Rest

Tags: mysql, encryption, mariadb, rhel6

I'm trying to configure a MariaDB 10.1 installation with encryption at rest, but when I add plugin-load-add=file_key_management_plugin.so to the conf file, mariadb won't start. And throws the following error:

```
2016-03-23 22:03:18 139905990993952 [ERROR] Can't open shared library '/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/file_key_management_plugin.so' (errno: 0, cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I search I can't find the plugin file anywhere.

Is there are a specific RPM I need to install via YUM to get the plugin?

Comment: how did you install maria db? if you used yum to install it it should install normally. and what's encryption with rest? I'm sure that plugin can be updated with yum. Don't do anything custom with the installation. You should delete the installation and remove /var/lib and start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-1014-release-notes/ .  Based on it, it might be as simple as dropping `_plugin` from the name.